# Pygame, problema con pygame.display.flip() no funcia si lo pongo al final

Tags: python, pygame

Soy nuevo programando y tengo un ramo en donde usamos `Pygame` en python 2.7. La cuestión es que estaba probando cosas y cuando quería pintar la pantalla de blanco no pintaba y lo escribí así:

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
#Colors
Black = (   0,   0,   0)
White = ( 255, 255, 255)
Green = (   0, 255,   0)
Red   = ( 255,   0,   0)
Blue  = (   0,   0, 255)

#wind
size = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#win whi
screen.fill(White)

#ext win
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
#ani
corx = 400
cory = 200
speedx = 3
speedy = 3
corx += speedx
cory += speedy
#coor
pygame.draw.rect(screen, Red, (corx, cory, 80, 80))

pygame.display.flip()
```

Y no me actualiza la pantalla a pesar de que mi profesor siempre lo escribe así, intente pedir ayuda pero o no entendí nada o lo que me dijo no era realmente concluyente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `while True:` no termina nunca, por lo que nunca llegas a ejecutar las instrucciones que vienen a continuación. Es cosa de simple lógica.

Fijate en esta versión:

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
#Colors
Black = (   0,   0,   0)
White = ( 255, 255, 255)
Green = (   0, 255,   0)
Red   = ( 255,   0,   0)
Blue  = (   0,   0, 255)

#wind
size = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#win whi
screen.fill(White)
corx = 400
cory = 200
speedx = 3
speedy = 3
corx += speedx
cory += speedy
#coor
pygame.draw.rect(screen, Red, (corx, cory, 80, 80))
pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

#### Alternativa

O tal vez te olvidastes de la indentación:

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
#Colors
Black = (   0,   0,   0)
White = ( 255, 255, 255)
Green = (   0, 255,   0)
Red   = ( 255,   0,   0)
Blue  = (   0,   0, 255)

#wind
size = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#win whi
screen.fill(White)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        corx = 400
        cory = 200
        speedx = 3
        speedy = 3
        corx += speedx
        cory += speedy
        #coor
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Red, (corx, cory, 80, 80))
        pygame.display.flip()
```